# Visual Studio F6 key being intercepted as Ctrl-C

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I'm using Visual Studio 2022, and about a month ago something changed where the <kbd>F6</kbd> key would just become <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>.

I noticed this when my C# projects stopped being able to build, and I followed various online solutions to check and reset my keyboard settings (Visual C# 2005 and all that). All had no effect however.

Yesterday when trying to fix this I experimented again on the keyboard settings and happened to tap <kbd>F6</kbd> on the prompt for 'Press Shortcut Key' under a random selection, and got shocked when <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> appeared there. I couldn't find how this happened and more googling revealed no similar issues encountered and solved elsewhere.

[image]

I don't have many extensions installed which I guess should be the primary culprit to this: the last one I remember installing was Github Copilot but that has like just 3 known keyboard bindings and none that seem to be linked to such a behavior. Have also checked MSConfig and found no startup programs that might do this, and the only hardware/gaming app installed that might do this is my Razer Synapse but I only have a Razer keyboard on one machine with no specific macros or bindings detected while the problem happens across both of my machines, so it can't be Synapse.

This problem also only happens in VS: when I hit the key in, for example Notepad the same behavior is not observed.

Can anyone please help me find out how to restore <kbd>F6</kbd>'s behavior on VS?

Comment: Side note: you can use `<kbd>` to style text as key, i. e. `<kbd>F6</kbd>`

Comment: Cool just edited for that, thanks for the tip!